# CSS selector to find a link within plain text

Tags: jquery, css

I need to display text within an html page. The text contains potentially invalid hyperlinks in that about about half of the links in the text will generate HTTP 40* error messages when clicked. I have no control over the web service delivering the content with the links in it.

The HTML fragment I have to work with is:

```
<body>

<div id="myTextContent">
 The quick brown <a href="/link/to/page/generating/403">fox</a> jumped over the lazy dogs.
</div>

</body>
```

I'd like to replace `href="/link/to/page/generating/403"` with `href="#"`.

Is there an appropriate CSS selector that I can use to locate the link and replace the value of the href attribute?

Comment: What is the criteria for selecting the link? Any link in `myTextContent`? Any link on the page?

Comment: Yes, any link content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This really needs more clarification. As it stands, this question can only be answered if we can assume you want to target all `a` tags inside `#myTextContent`.  If that is the case:

```
$('#myTextContent a').attr('href', '#')
```

Comment: Thanks, as primarily a back end developer CSS is fairly new to me. Being able to ask noob questions helps. Still a clearly structured question with a clear answer - not sure where the down vote comes from. If somebody with my years of experience can't ask a noob question about a topic without getting a downvote, genuine new developers to the software industry asking questions don't stand a chance!

Comment: Glad I could help. I think the only confusing part was the lack of information in your explanation about the setup of the page. I guessed based on the code example, but it would have been much clearer to say something like, "I want to target all of the links that might end up in this `myTextContent` div."  But yes, it's not uncommon to get a summary downvote if you haven't been _extremely_ clear on what you're asking, and that's not helpful.

Comment: Sometimes downvotes are given if someone thinks it falls foul of this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users

Comment: In my view it doesn't. The bit that confused me was the part about the plain text. I haven't found any documentation about selecting elements within plain text anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `[]` attribute selector to target specific urls without affecting *all* urls:

```js
$('a[href="/link/to/page/generating/403"]').attr("href", "notfound.html")
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="/link/to/page/generating/403">fox</a>
<a href="/anotherlink/not/changed">link</a>
```